# What references, foreign_keys do I need to add for these associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these associations in my Rails 4.2 app. I don't understand how to setup the proper references/foreign_keys between instructors and courses.

So far both instructors and courses tables have a local_id (local reference).
Local is a training center they both belong to.

```
class Local < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :instructors
  has_many :courses
end

class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :local
  has_many :courses, through: :locals
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :local
  has_many :instructors, through: :locals
end
```

Do I add a foreign_key to the courses table? Like this:

```
add_foreign_key :courses, :instructors
```

I read something about when having many to many associations we need a "join table" cause we need to store many ids. I guess Local is just that in this case.

Or do I need another table(Model) that `belongs_to :instructor, :course`?

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is [locale](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/locale) not local.

Comment: Oups yes. I had a hard time finding a good translation for the swedish lokal. I'll rename it to venue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would set it up for maximum flexibility.

### Instructors and Courses

Lets set up a many to many relationship with a join model which we call `Employment`.

We can generate the model with:

```
rails g model employment instructor:belongs_to course:belongs_to
```

Which will give us this:

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
  belongs_to :course
end
```

`employments` will have the `instructor_id` and `course_id` foreign keys. This lets us assign any number of instructors to a course and vice versa.

So let's put the join model to use:

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :courses, through: :employments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :instructors, through: :employments
end
```

### Venues and Courses

I would recommend you rename your `Local` model `Venue` as it's the common english term for the place where a course or event is held. `Locale` is awkward since it collides with [a separate concept in web applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) and may cause name clashes.

And we should probably set it up as many to many to account for the complexities of real life.

So again:

```
rails g model booking venue:belongs_to course:belongs_to
```

---

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :course
end
```

`bookings` will have the `venue_id` and `course_id` foreign keys.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base # was Local
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :courses, through: :bookings
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :venues, through: :bookings
end
```

### More reading:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association
- http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Comment: I have a few more models that are the same as Course. Such as Practice. Can I use the Employment model for those, or do I need to create more join tables? Thanks for the quick and excellent answer!

Comment: You could use the Employment model but you would need to change the relation to be a [polymorpic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: When using a polymorphic association. Would  it be better to have the polymorphic association at the Venue model and skip the Employment join table? So in the Course model I would have `has_many :instructors, through: :venue, source: :employable, source_type: 'Course'`. Seems logical and would give the same flexiblity right?

Comment: No, if you skip the Employment table and add an `instructor_id` to Venue you are creating a one-to-one relation between a venue and a instructor.

Comment: Ok. I just created a new rails app with my models and its associations. Company -> Venue -> Instructor + Course. Created Employment model with `belongs_to :employable, polymorphic: true` (employable_id + employable_type attributes) and added `has_many :instructors, through: :employments, source: :employable, source_type: 'Course'` in Course model and vice versa in Instructor model.

Went in to rails console and created a company, created a venue for it, created a instructor and a course for that venue. All worked. But I get a NoMethodError for company.venues.courses.instructors.

Comment: When creating instructor and doing `instructor.courses` I got `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :employments in model Instructor`

Comment: Did you skip the step of adding 'has_many :employments' to Instructor?

Comment: Had put wrong class in source_type's. All works. Thanks for your help and patience max. I've learned alot theses days.